# How to check if 1/a == 1/b + 1/c in c++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to check if `1/a == 1/b + 1/c` in c++.
`a`, `b` and `c` are positive integers and `a` is between 1 and 10000.

I'm currently getting wrong answers due to floating point precision and I cannot find a way to do this comparison without using floats.

How do I get a correct answer?

Comment: I think a little high school algebra would allow you to solve this without using floats.

Comment: This isn't really a C++ question ... it really should be retagged as an algebra question ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this will help you:

1/a = 1/b + 1/c

1 = a/b + a/c

1 = (ac + ab)/bc

bc = ac + ab #no longer needs division

Answer (score 9):

Multiply both sides of the equation by `a*b*c` to get

```
b*c == a*c + a*b
```

Comment: The point is that since no division is used you will not be needing floating pointers.

Comment: As long as `b` and `c` are also non-zero.

Comment: @ZacHowland: If any are zero, there's no "correct" answer, so whatever this equation gives is as good an answer as any. But the question did specify "positive integers".

Comment: @MikeSeymour Agreed.  The only issue is that the multiplication version of the problem does not explicitly enforce the non-zero requirement (whereas the division representation does).

Answer (score 4):

```
a(b+c)==b*c
```

should work just fine :)

Answer (score 1):

When comparing floating point values it's often not practical to look for exact matches because of precision issues.  They can foil even the simplest of problems.

```
double d = sqrt(2);
cout << (d * d) == 2 // false
```

Instead you often have to test to see if the values are within a certain error margin

```
fabs((d * d) - 2) < .001  // true
```

Comment: Care to add a comment to go with the -1?

Comment: I didn't vote, but this entire problem can be done without worrying about floating points at all.

Comment: @ZacHowland I agree but the OP stated specifically they were running into floating point precision issues. I'm going to guess he's running into a problem like the one i stated

Comment: No, he stated he couldn't figure out a way to do this without using floats.  The answer is not to use floats, but to do the math correctly to not use them.

Comment: @ZacHowland However the floating point container can cover greater range of numbers. It depends on the exact use-case.

Comment: @ZacHowland he specifically said " getting wrong answers due to floating point precision". Not sure how you can interpret that any other way than he's running into floating point precision problems

Comment: @Erbureth I think we're all aware of the greater range afforded by floating point data types, but given that the OP mentions all 3 variables involved are integral types, and that he *cannot find a way to do this comparison without using floats*, the other answers that show how floats can be avoided are better.

Comment: @JaredPar "I'm currently getting wrong answers due to floating point precision and **I cannot find a way to do this comparison without using floats.**"  You must read the whole sentence :)

Comment: @ZacHowland i read the whole sentence and I answered the first part of the problem. Others had already taken care of the non-floating point portion.

Comment: @Praetorian Yes, I read the question. However I'd like to point out that the solutions isn't black or white, as the multiplication can overflow where floats wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a programming question, I assume you mean `int` division.

Now, `1/a` where `a` is a positive `int`teger type is either `0` or `1`, and in fact is `1` iff `a==1`.

We can abuse `bool` casts as follows:

```
(a==1) == ((b==1)+(c==1))
```

and we avoid any and all use of `float`s.

Answer (score 0):

You could always turn this into a class called fraction. Use the common denominator to convert all 3 variables to the same denominator, add b and c, then compare to a.